# Передача параметров в класс

Tags: c++

Необходимо создать класс. Он будет унаследован от одного из стандартных классов достаточно популярной библиотеки (не важно - предком может быть `QObject Qt` или `CObject` из `MFC`). При этом возникает проблема, что в класс нужно передать определенное количество параметров. Их можно передать тремя способами:

1. в конструкторе.
2. с помощью некой дополнительной сущности в виде метода `init()` с нужным количеством параметров.
3. сделать нужное количество сеттеров и внутренних переменных класса, которые будут устанавливаться в процессе работы.

У каждого способа есть плюсы и минусы. У конструктора есть серьезный плюс, что объект сразу получается готовый. У него нет промежуточных состояний. С методом `init()` получается, что его нужно не забыть вызвать с правильными аргументами один раз при создании объекта. Дальнейшие вызовы нежелательны (можно, например, устроить себе утечки памяти). С другой стороны, между вызовом конструктора и ф-цией `init()` объект получается в каком-то непонятном промежуточном состоянии, когда его полноценное использование невозможно. В третьем случае из-за обилия ф-ций запросто можно запутаться и что-то забыть. При этом у всех внутренних переменных класса, получается, должны быть какие-то значения "по умолчанию", иначе без вызова этих сеттеров экземпляр класс будет неработоспособен. С конструкторами минус мне кажется в том, что если существует достаточно большое кол-во опциональных входных параметров, то получается жесткая путаница в голове у компилятора и он просто не сможет собрать код. В конце-концов можно все параметры попытаться запаковать в структуру и передавать в конструктор указатель на нее. Но как-то это не лаконично.

Например,

```
MyObject::MyObject(int a, int b, int c); // GOOD. никаких параметров по умолчанию
MyObject::MyObject(int a = 1, int b = 2; int c = 4); // GOOD
MyObject::MyObject(QObject *parent = 0, int b = 2, int c = 4); //а оно вообще соберется? и не будет ли конфликта с предыдущим вариантом?

typedef struct {int *first; QObject **parent; int *b; int *c;} arguments;
QObject *parent = 0; int b = 2; int c = 4;
arguments ar = {NULL, &parent, &b, &c}; // NULL - как бы аргумента "нет"
MyObject::MyObject(arguments &data); // нифига неизящно
```

Короче, прошу совета - как лучше делать. Понятно, что универсальных случаев нет, но какие-то рекомендации должны существовать.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

По поводу трех способов. 2 (с методом init) - это грустно. Инициализация должна быть внутри конструктора. Хотя, некоторые "метры", изобретая Tizen (новую ОС для телефонов), выдают [перлы](https://developer.tizen.org/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.tizen.native.apireference%2FclassTizen_1_1Base_1_1Collection_1_1HashMap.html). Доставляет и вызов метода `RemoveAll` в конце - как бы uninit:)

третий способ это размазанный init. По факту (если set'еры имеют хоть какую то логику), приведет к трудностям инициализации - объект может находиться в состоянии кота одного известного ученого([комикс в тему](http://comicsbook.ru/funny/92805?zhivoy-i-mertvyy)).

> > С конструкторами минус мне кажется в том, что если существует достаточно большое кол-во опциональных входных параметров, то получается жесткая путаница в голове у компилятора и он просто не сможет собрать код.

Думаю, у программиста скорее наступит путаница:) а компилятор либо скомпилирует, либо нет.

Как бы я делал. У таких сложных классов сделал бы приватные конструкторы (что бы их кто не попади не конструировал). Отдельно сделал бы фабрику, которая по запросу отдавала сконструированный объект (такая себе сборка паттернов фабрика и строитель).

Если какой то объект может существовать в десяти разных вариантах, то значит нужно десять разных функций. При этом эти функции могут иметь один-два параметра, так и принимать другой класс/структру в качестве параметра. Так как имена будут разными, то и компилятор не запутается, и человек. (подсмотреть [пример](http://cpp-reference.ru/patterns/creational-patterns/factory-method/) ).

Второй вариант - это сделать класс, у которого конструктор будет принимать десятки параметров (но мне смутно вериться, что такой класс реально нужен, об этом ниже). И этот конструктор должен быть `protected`. На каждый специфический случай заводится отдельный наследник с минимумом параметров в конструкторе. Если в какой то момент кажется, что нужно добавить ещё [over9000](http://lurkmore.to/Over9000) параметров, нужно подумать, может нужно 2-3 различных класса наследника? Пример из реальной жизни - в windows много оконных элементов - окна. и представьте, если бы у Вас был только один класс окно, который делал все разновидности - окно, кнопку, поле редактирования.

Третий способ. То, что нужно так много параметров, подсказывает, что похоже проектируется ["божественный класс"](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82). Поэтому и вылазят такие сложности. Может с этого класса можно выделить часть данных+кода в отдельный класс/классы? А там и архитектура упростится.

Answer (score 4):

Универсального рецепта нету, в каждом сложном случае приходится делать по-своему.

В хорошем случае (немного входных данных, немного различных комбинаций) старайтесь предпочитать конструктор. Функция типа `init` не так уж плоха, если все в вашем проекте все знают о такой архитектуре. Но в случае, когда она нужна (несколько разных конструкторов), есть лучшее решение: статические factory-методы:

```
class Point
{
    double x, y;
    Point(double anX, double aY) : x(anX), y(aY) {}
public:
    static Point* FromCartesian(double x, double y)
    {
        return new Point(x, y);
    }
    static Point* FromPolar(double r, double phi)
    {
        return new Point(r * cos(phi), r * sin(phi));
    }
};
```

Они не хуже `init`-методов, в них нету промежуточного, «не готового к жизни» состояния объектов, и они устраняют проблемы с одинаковыми сигнатурами (представьте себе, как бы вы сделали конструкторы, инициализирующие как с декартовыми, так и с полярными координатами?).

Существуют, однако, достаточно случаи, когда в классе реально много параметров. Примером тому могут служить, например, классы, представляющие графические элементы в WPF, например, [`Grid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.aspx) (да, это не C++, но дизайн — везде дизайн). Для подобных классов не существует единого решения. Я бы отметил два подхода.

1) Подход как в упомянутом классе `Grid`. Объект содержит лишь один конструктор, и спроектирован так, что всегда находится в правильном, валидном состоянии (да, это требует более аккуратного программирования).

Достоинство — не надо заботиться об установке параметров, для которых подходит значение по умолчанию (аргументы по умолчанию в конструкторах достаточно слабо помогают).

Недостаток — то, что валидное состояние с точки зрения объекта ещё не означает валидного состояния с точки зрения пользователя этого объекта. Например, если объект сразу после создания начинает посылать сообщения, пользователь, возможно, хотел бы «запустить» объект лишь после того, как подпишется на эти сообщения. Это налагает требования к дизайну объекта: подобные use case'ы должны быть предусмотрены при разработке.

2) Подход, более типичный для объектов, которые надо долго конфигурировать и лишь затем запустить — разделить сущности «параметры класса» и «сам класс» по двум разным классам. Упрощённый пример:

```
class MessageBoxArgs
{
public:
    std::wstring TitleLocId;
    loc::ILocalizableTextSource* Content;

    ui::Window* Owner;
    std::vector<ui:PredefinedButtonId> PredefinedButtons;
    ui:PredefinedButtonId DefaultButton;
    ui:PredefinedButtonId SelectedButton;

    ctrl::INeverShowAgain* NeverShowAgainHandler;

    // можно добавить несколько вспомогательных методов

    MessageBox* Show();

    // популярные конструкторы
    static MessageBox* Show(wchar_t* content);
    static MessageBox* Show(wchar_t* content, wchar_t* title);
};
```

Здесь пользователь может как угодно конфигурировать будущий `MessageBox` при помощи `MessageBoxParameters`, но создание происходит лишь внутри вызова `Show()`.

Достоинство такого подхода — полная гибкость задания параметров объекта. Недостаток — громоздкость записи, с которой можно бороться, вынося часто используемые конструкторы как отдельные factory-методы.